# How to run grunt 0.4.* without grunt-cli

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I wonder if it's possible to run grunt 0.4.* without having installed grunt-cli.

I understand that grunt-cli looks for the version of grunt installed in node-modules in my project directory in order to run that version of grunt but...is it possible to run grunt without having grunt-cli installed? How?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The real question here is, why you want to do it?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for ask. I think of two cases: One is running grunt from an automated script and the second is having the whole system checked-in in the repository, for ease of installing. Another case could be not having admin permissions to install a package globally.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try

```
node -e "require('grunt').cli();"
```

if you're on a mac / unix

Answer (score 26):

The grunt-cli is a very small amount of code. If I was you I would look through it in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/blob/master/bin/grunt). That way you will learn what it does, and it's very easy to do the same.

I have had luck with running it with no grunt-cli. You can do it with the following command:

```
node -e "require('grunt').cli()"
```

If you want to specify tasks you can do it like this:

```
node -e "var g = require('grunt'); g.cli.tasks = ['default']; g.cli()"
```

Comment: Yeah!! Thank you Allan, your code didn't work on my mac, but going into REPL and running `require('grunt').cli();` worked in the command line. And putting the same line of code in a script also worked :)

Comment: How would you target a specific task with this? ex. `grunt default`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try from some other script:

```
var grunt = require('grunt');
grunt.cli();
```

That will look for the grunt package and execute the Gruntfile.js.